# How to show number in thoulsends units in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which shows value of sales:

```
Select saleid,round(valueofsale) as value
from sales
```

the column valueofsale is type `numeric(16,4)`.

This shows:

```
saleid  value
 1       1400
 2       15451
 3       1654
 7       120
```

I want to display value in thoulsends, So i should "ommit" the last 3 digits.
This is not really ommit as much as round it properly.
example:

```
value = 1500 should be displayed as: 2  (round to 2000 and ommit 3 zeors)
value = 1499 should be displayed as: 1  (round to 1000 and ommit 3 zeors)
value = 24001 should be displayed as: 24  (round to 24000 and ommit 3 zeors)
```

basicly the logic is 3 last digits >=500 "round up", 3 last digits <500 "round down".

desired result for above table:

```
saleid  value
 1       1
 2       15
 3       2
 7       0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `round(value / 1000)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this does not work. example: `select round(501/1000)` gives `0` while it should give `1`

Comment: try `round(value / 1000.0)`

Comment: Works for me:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a63e/1 Are you sure `value` is defined as `numeric`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes... round(value / 1000.0) works.